# Display images on corners so images stay on the same place after resizing window

Tags: jquery, css, html, jquery-mobile

I'm building an mobile app with `HTML5` and with Jquery Mobile , what I'm trying to do is to display 2 images, one on the right side and the other on the left side. What important is when resizing window browser, the images should not disappear and be shown always one in right and one in left sides, so it will fit to different mobile screens.

I tried to use CSS :
 `float:right`, `left:85%` ...

But after resizing it just disappear....

Comment: what about absolute positioning? then `right : 0;`

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing any code, I'm not sure what you've tried. But you can achieve this using the following:

```
<div style="position:fixed;left:0;"><img src="fakeimageurl.jpg" width="100" /></div>
<div style="position:fixed;right:0;"><img src="fakeimageurl.jpg" width="100" /></div>
```

or if you want the images not to move with the scroll...

```
<div style="position:absolute;left:0;"><img src="fakeimageurl.jpg" width="100" /></div>
<div style="position:absolute;right:0;"><img src="fakeimageurl.jpg" width="100" /></div>
```

Comment: I just want to be sure It's working...what if I would like to have those 2 images in the middle,but with some free space between them?

Comment: play with the left and right values. the number indicates how far from the left or right respectively they will appear. The space between them would be informed by how close you moved them together pushing them off left and right. Try playing with the code see if it works for you.

Comment: that i understand,dont I have to use % instead px...because now the images despair after resizing.

Comment: @Alex Opet i tried the next code: 

`<div style="position:absolute;left: 35%;"><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/sniffels/christmas/256/house-icon.png" width="100"></div>
<div style="position:absolute;right: 35%;"><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/archigraphs/collection/256/House-icon.png" width="100"></div>` but the space between them changes when resizing the window...I want it stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is an example](http://codepen.io/josiahruddell/pen/oclwK) to get you started. Try re-sizing the browser.

I suggest using psuedo `before` and `after` selectors to create your background image markup since this in not something you desire semantically to be on the page

Basic markup:

```
<div id="main">
    Page content
</div>
```

Basic CSS:

```
#main { position: relative; z-index: 1 }
#main:before { content: ''; z-index: -1; position: absolute; top:0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 50%;  }
#main:after { content: ''; z-index: -1; position: absolute; top:0; bottom: 0; right: 0; left: 50%; }
```

The `top:0`, `bottom:0` stretches the elements to the full height of the target container (`#main`) while the `left`/`right` `0`/`50%` occupy the appropriate half.

Now set the background image on `before` and `after` definitions. For scaling background images you could also utilize [`background-size`](http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/) although, this may not be necessary.